# How to know which optimizations are turned on in gcc?

Tags: optimization, gcc

I've seen that you can see the optimizations which are turned on using:

```
gcc -O2 -Q --help=optimizers
```

but the thing is that it only shows optimizations that have a flag.

Do you know if there's a way to find the others ?

This is maybe stupid since with no flag how would they describe the optimizations...but anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Your best source of information may be the ['Optimize Options' section of the GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options).

Comment: it was the page i was looking at. But for nstance, it never says that it's going to remove never referenced functions.